# Bash script to start process, wait random, kill process, restart

Tags: linux, bash, random

I'm an absolute beginner and am trying to create a bash script to randomize the start and exit of a command line app. I plan to autostart the script on boot (Crunchbang) after a slight delay with the following in autostart.sh (found here: http://interwebworld.co.uk/2011/10/23/how-to-launch-programs-automatically-at-startup-in-crunchbang-linux/ )

```
(sleep 300s && /home/myuser/Scripts/randomizer.sh) &
```

This is essentially what I need to accomplish in the randomizer.sh script, in a bit of pseudocode:

```
start applicationfile
wait a random period of time
if applicationfile is still running
    kill its process
    wait a random period of time
    exit this script and restart this script
else exit this script and restart this script
```

The randomizer.sh as I have it so far and which I'd welcome some help with, is as follows (containing remnants of the pseudocode), and the sleep delay found here: http://blog.buberel.org/2010/07/howto-random-sleep-duration-in-bash.html

```
/path/to/applicationfile -s 111.222.333.444 -u username -p password
sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 150 ) + 60 ]m
if applicationfile is still running
    kill $(ps aux | grep '[u]sername' | awk '{print $2}')
    sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 150 ) + 60 ]m
    exec $randomizer.sh
else exec $randomizer.sh
```

I "think" the non-pseudo parts should work pretty much as they are, but please correct me or adjust if I'm wrong. The initial applicationfile command line works as it is, and I already tested the process kill line and it works as expected. Applicationfile doesn't have a built-in way to end itself from commandline, but the dead connection on the remote machine will be killed after 5 minutes of being killed locally, so killing it locally is acceptable for my needs.

What I don't have any idea how to handle is the line above the kill, which checks "if" the process is running in the first place. Sorry for the wall of text but I wanted to show I've done as much as I could already.

Answer (score 20):

In bash, `$!` is the PID of the last launched process, so something patterned along the lines of this should work:

```
mycommand &
last_pid=$!
sleep( $RANDOM )
kill -KILL $last_pid
```

You can, of course, fiddle around to change the signal you send, the relationship between $RANDOM and the time you want to sleep, etc.

It's somewhat unlikely that a new process will get the same PID unless either a) the sleep time is very long or b) your machine launches a lot of short-lived processes. On Linux, PIDs are allocated cyclically with a max of 32,765, so, roughly speaking, you would have to have launched about that many processes in the sleep time to risk hitting the same PID belonging to a different process. If that's a risk, you could add a test (technically, there's a race here, but it's very unlikely to be a problem). The following seems like it would do what you want.

```
signal=KILL

sleep_a_while () {
    sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 150 ) + 60 ]m
}

while true; do
    # Note: command launched in background:
    /path/to/applicationfile -s 111.222.333.444 -u username -p password &

    # Save PID of command just launched:
    last_pid=$!

    # Sleep for a while:
    sleep_a_while

    # See if the command is still running, and kill it and sleep more if it is:
    if ps -p $last_pid -o comm= | grep -qs '^applicationfile$'; then
        kill -$signal $last_pid 2> /dev/null
        sleep_a_while
    fi

    # Go back to the beginning and launch the command again
done
```

I've replaced the self-`exec` with an equivalent loop.

On the `kill` line, the redirect of `stderr` to `/dev/null` is desirable because of a race. The process might exit naturally between the time the `ps` completes and the time that the `kill` is executed, resulting in a harmless error message. This race is unavoidable (and harmless) unless the test that the PID exists and the sending of the signal are coincident.

If there is intended to be at most *one* instance of `applicationfile` running at a time, then this race can be avoided entirely by replacing:

```
# See if the command is still running, and kill it and sleep more if it is:
if ps -p $last_pid -o comm= | grep -qs '^applicationfile$'; then
    kill -$signal $last_pid 2> /dev/null
    sleep_a_while
fi
```

With:

```
killall -q applicationfile && sleep_a_while
```

If this cannot be used, Keith Reynolds's variant of the test is better, since it avoids an unnecessary `grep`, i.e. using:

```
# See if the command is still running, and kill it and sleep more if it is:
if [ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm=)" = "applicationfile" ]; then
    kill -$signal $last_pid 2> /dev/null
    sleep_a_while
fi
```

Comment: So assign PID to a variable and then kill that PID? Shouldn't the kill be in an 'if', to kill the process *only if* it's actually still alive? What if some other factor (i.e. remote disconnect, app crash, etc) stopped that process in the meantime and another process has been given that ID and is then mistakenly killed?

Also, the second sleep should only happen inside an "if" so if the process *has* been killed prematurely, the script skips the second sleep and goes straight to restart. But if the script is still running, then kill it, *then sleep some more*, then restart.

Comment: I've updated my answer, trying to mirror the logic of your question as closely as possible. I hope it works for you.

Comment: The code `if ps -p $last_pid -o comm= | grep '^applicationfile$'; then` unnecessarily spits out the string applicationfile

Comment: @Emmet & Keith: Thank you both for your valuable input and suggestions. I'm going to try both of your variants this weekend and see which works best, and then will post a follow-up.

Comment: Emmet, I've just run your version through some tests and it seems that last_pid is actually killing the sleep process and not the executable process. The sequence is as follows: 1. GUI interface opens on the VM I'm testing in. 2. GUI successfully logs in to remote server. 3. 'ps aufx' shows random times in each test, so the sleep randomizer is working as expected. 4. Sleep time expires 5. A second GUI *immediately* opens and original GUI remains. -- Also, the second sleep period never runs. After several loops, 'ps aufx' shows multiple PIDs of executable, but only 1 sleep PID.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by “it seems that last_pid is killing the ...”. `last_pid` is just the PID saved from `$!`; it doesn't kill anything. The only way I can think of for the `sleep` to be killed would be if `/path/to/applicationfile` is actually a path to this script itself, since then the running script would be killed, most likely while `sleep`ing (because that's most of what it does). Also, I don't know the context, so telling me about how the GUIs and VMs behave doesn't mean anything to me because I don't know how they relate to this script or what the expected behavior is.

Comment: I reversed the terms in my previous post.. it seemed that "kill" is killing "sleep" but I don't know for sure. What is certain is that the second sleep never happens, the application immediately opens a second copy of itself and tries to login over the first, which logs out the first, and prevents the second from logging in because the first login hasn't been fully logged out on the server yet.

Comment: The second `sleep` will happen if, and only if, a previously launched `application_file` process still exists and is `kill`ed, otherwise the program will go back to the start of the loop and immediately start another `application_file` process once the first `sleep` is over. Your original question was expressed in a generic way, so all these specific details about how some application behaves logging into some server or other *tell me nothing* because I don't know how these details are related to the generic problem and the script. It may be clear to you, but I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: As I said, beginner here, so I may not be clear:) Let me know what additional info is needed. I'm running the script from cli to test. It opens application_file GUI, logs into remote, and creates random sleep. Sleep expires. Script checks if application_file is still running. It is. Expected behavior: Script should now kill application_file, sleep again, then restart application file. Actual behavior: Script does not kill application_file. Script does not sleep again. Script immediately opens a new copy of application_file. ps aufx now shows two application_file processes and 1 sleep process.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that applicationfile isn't being matched in the `if` statement. In manual tests I was originally using the `kill $(ps aux | grep '[u]sername' | awk '{print $2}')` statement in my OP because it never failed, but the current script is not killing applicationfile or sleeping, it's just starting another copy of applicationfile on top of itself, as if the entire `if` were being ignored.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this code for your randomizer.sh**

```
min_val=60
range=150
while true ; do
    run_this_command &
    last_pid=$!
    sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % $range ) + $min_val ]
    { [ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm= )" ] && \
      [ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm= )" = run_this_command ]; 
    } && { kill -KILL $last_pid ;}
done
```

**Some notes:**

1. Rather than using the exec statement. You can accomplish what your trying to do more simply by staying inside a while loop. The randomiser.sh I present is only read from the hard drive once.
2. The code `{ [ condition ] && { command ;} && command` runs faster than `if [ condition ]; then command, else command; fi`
3. With the variable $last_pid assigned to the value of $!, the command `ps -p $last_pid -o comm=` will spit out the name of the process with the PID of `$last_pid`. If there is no PID with that value then its exist code is 1.

---

**Amended to meet the additional random wait period before start requirement:**

```
# Minimum and range values for random Wait before start in seconds
MinA=60;RangeA=150 
# Minimum and range values for random Wait before kill in seconds
MinB=60; RangeB=150 # 
while true ; do
    sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % $RangeA ) + $MinA ] 
    run_this_command &
    last_pid=$!
    sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % $RangeB ) + $MinB ] 
    { [ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm= )" ] && \
      [ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm= )" = run_this_command ]
    } && \{ kill -KILL $last_pid ;}
done
```

Comment: The test (3.) doesn't achieve anything, IMHO. Without it, if the process doesn't exist, `kill` will just fail harmlessly. If the process exists, it will be `kill`ed whether or not it is an instance of `run_this_command`. OP identified PID reuse as a potential issue earlier.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I'm saying that nothing on that line (with the `&&`) materially affects the overall behavior vs. simply having `kill -KILL $last_pid` except for a single harmless error message (that can be silenced). Explanation: If the LHS succeeds, the process will be killed *whether or not the process is an instance of `run_this_command`*. If the LHS fails, the RHS is not run, which is functionally identical to killing a PID that does not exist. The only reason to have the test at all is to ensure that the PID to be killed corresponds to an instance of `run_this_command`. See?

Comment: If you used `[ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm=)" = "run_this_command" ] && kill -KILL $last_pid`, it would make perfect sense. Otherwise you might as well just do `ps $last_pid > /dev/null && kill -KILL $last_pid` or just `kill -KILL $last_pid > /dev/null`.

Comment: @Emmet I respectfully disagree. Running `[ "$(ps -p 1 -o comm=" ) ] && echo "PID exist"` finishes with `PID exist` whereas `[ "$(ps -p 100 -o comm= )" ] && echo "PID exist"` finishes with nothing to the terminal because there is no process with the ID 100. This behavior is entirely different than having just `kill -KILL $last_pid` as you suggested. This is so because the exit code of `ps -p 100 -o comm=`  effects [ "$(ps -p 100 -o comm=)" ]` the same way the exit code of true effect `[ true ] && echo exit code is 0`  and the exit code of false effects `[ false ] || echo exit code is 1`

Comment: First: suppose `run_this_command` gets PID 1000, but exits almost immediately, and the `sleep` is for its maximum value of 3½ hours. 3 hours into the sleep, an unrelated daemon is launched and gets PID 1000 because the PID assignments have wrapped around. Your solution will kill the unrelated daemon. This was identified as a potential issue by the OP.

Comment: Second: testing if a process exists and then killing it if it does is unarguably functionally identical (except that it introduces a race) to simply trying to kill it. Either the PID (say 100) corresponds to a running process or it does not. If it does, the `ps` succeeds and it gets killed. If PID 100 does not exist, the `ps` fails and it does not get killed. If there is no `ps` guard and you just use `kill -KILL 100`, the process gets killed if 100 exists. If PID 100 does not exist, it obviously can't be killed and kill produces a trivial error message *which you have to suppress anyway*.

Comment: @Emmet Killing the wrong process that has the same PID after the original process was killed or removed and the PID table wraps around is a valid but separate concern brought to my attention. I will fix it with '{ [ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm= )" ] && [ "$(ps -p $last_pid -o comm= )" = run_this_command ]; } && { kill -KILL $last_pid ;}'

Comment: Keith: I just tested this version and the result is identical to Emmet's, i.e. the application logs in correctly to the remote machine, and then is forcibly killed by the tight timing I've applied for testing. If forcibly killed by the script it should be waiting through a second sleep period, but the second sleep period never happens. The application immediately opens a second copy of itself and tries to login again.. Since the original copy is still logged in, the second copy disconnects the first, then can't log in itself because the remote server hasn't yet logged out the first instance.

Comment: @graphics.guy I see where the script, as is, failed to meet your stated  requirements. I may amend a second script to the end of my solution to accommodate the one requirement left out.