# Tagging a unix process / storing pid on disk?

Tags: bash, unix

So, I need to run a program, *not* keep track of its PID (in memory, at least), and later kill that program. Any ideas? My immediate thought was to tag the process with something I could find later, but that seems a bust. My next thought was to store on disk the PID, but I've no idea what the convention for that sort of thing is. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why the additional constraint of NOT storing the PID in memory? You could try something along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22867130/319204 What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward (and common case) is, as you and chepner already mentioned, to store it in a pid file. For this:

If it's a system wide programm:

```
/var/run/prog.pid
```

If it's a system installed program that might be run multiple times:

```
/var/run/prog/prog_instance.pid
```

If it's a user local program:

```
$HOME/.prog/prog.pid
```

Other options might be to use `pgrep` for finding it as long as you can uniquely define the calling command. For example pass a dummy argument not used and use it for retrieval:

```
$ prog.sg --instance_1234 &
$ pgrep -f -- '--instance_1234'
3523
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program can create a directory under `/var/run/` to store such files. For instance, if your program is `myprog`  it might store its PID on startup in

```
/var/run/myprog/PID
```

If your program could have multiple instances running at the same time, you might use the PID itself in the file name, along with its startup time, to ensure a unique file name for each instance.

```
/var/run/myprog/201410302306.1283.pid
```

(Note that if you use the PID in the file name, it's up to you if you actually write the PID in the file itself; an empty file would suffice.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `start-stop-daemon` to start a program and kill it later. It has a lot of options to find the programm, the most usefull is the --pid that stores and retrive the pid from a file in filesystem, usually in `/var/run` (pay attention to file system privileges to write in it).

See the man pages for more tips.